# Magento 2 Numeric value out of range: 167 Out of range value for column 'value_id'

Tags: magento2

While I am trying to save the product from admin i am getting error like

```
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 167 Out of range value for column 'value_id' at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_text` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = VALUES(`value`)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fixed it?

Comment: Did you try this? 
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Technical-Issues/HELP-error-SQLSTATE-22003-Numeric-value-out-of-range-167-Out-of/m-p/82851#M7387

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following fixes at database structure. All commands are harmless to store functionality.

```
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text` CHANGE `value_id` `value_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID';
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int` CHANGE `value_id` `value_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID';
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` CHANGE `value_id` `value_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID';
```

In my case was the **catalog_product_entity_int**